# Randomly select on Data Frame, for unique rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing 10k rows, for a given column X I have duplicated values, How can we do to select randomly ONLY ONE ROW containing this value in this column ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I'm assuming you want to subsample the entire data frame, keeping one (randomly chosen) row per "duplicate class". Something like

```
library(plyr)
subsampled_data <- ddply(mydata,.(X),
    function(x) {
          x[sample(nrow(x),size=1),]
    })
```

Should work (**not tested!**)

Comment: This interpretation of the OP's (cryptic) question seems more likely than mine, for which I was going to suggest `df[sample(which(df$X == myVal),1),]`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am trying Ben's suggestion, Joran, how to do if I want to apply this to all colum value because myVal as suggested in your snippets change along my column X, which means I have hundreds of 5 for example and hundreds of 8s etc etc

Comment: @Rad Ben's solution will handle that; mine will not. We interpreted your question differently.

Comment: is it normal that it takes so much time, well I have a huge dataframe of 1 million rows, but it doesn't bug at least :)

Comment: @Rad Generally `ddply` is known for elegant simplicity, and not necessarily speed. See my answer below for another option to consider.

Answer (score 6):

My first instinct would have been something like Ben's elegant `ddply` solution. However, knowing now that you have such a large data set, there are definitely faster ways. Here is one that will be many times faster if you have many unique values:

```
RemoveDups <- function(df, column) {
  inds = sample(1:nrow(df))  
  df   = df[inds, ]

  dups = duplicated(df[, column])
  df   = df[!dups, ]
  inds = inds[!dups]

  df[sort(inds, index=T)$ix, ]
}
```

Simulate some data (here with many unique values):

```
n.row = 10^6
n.col = 3

set.seed(12345)
data  = data.frame(matrix(sample(1000, n.row*n.col, replace=T), nrow=n.row))
```

Compare the 2 methods:

```
> system.time(ddply(data, 'X1', function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), size=1), ]))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.264   0.921   4.315 
> system.time(RemoveDups(data, 'X1'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.375   0.025   0.399
```

Comment: Elegant ! Awesome, Thanks John